# Xen need to realize 2 lan interfaces 1 - for Lan between domU and 2 - Internet

Tags: networking, xen, local-area-network, bridge

Anyone know how to realize lan between domU machines at one interface and actually global net at another interface? I reading wiki about routing and bridging and unable to fully understand it http://wiki.xensource.com/xenwiki/XenNetRoutingWithPrivateNetwork

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at bridging. You can imagine a bridge as something like a virtual switch.
So build an internal bridge by not attaching an interface of your Dom0.
To connect to the outside world build a second bridge an connect your Dom0-network-interface-card to it.

If you provide more information about the OS you are using we can answer more specific.